# SQLite comparing array of IDs with those stored in the database as a string

Tags: php, sqlite, search

I am using SQLite as my database. In a table I have a column called projectIds, this stores a comma separated string of a bunch of IDs (ints). I want to create a way to search that table to return all rows that have specific projectIds stored.

Is it possible the way I have it stored? Is there some way of taking in an array of projectIds and creating a query that will check the projectIds column if any of those IDs exist?

e.g.

```
Return me all rows in the table that have one of these projectIds in it: [1,2,3,4]

Table:
row1 "1,3,4"
row2 "1"
row3 "5,6"

I should be returned rows 1 and 2.
```

Is there a cever way of taking my array and comparing with the projectIds column that is a string of IDs?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be to change your database schema so that you have a separate table containing rows like (refid, projectId), where refid refers back to your existing table.

You could also try using the LIKE operator, so querying for [1,2,3] becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE projectIds LIKE '%,1,%' OR projectIds LIKE '%,2,%' OR projectIds LIKE '%,3,%'
```

But that wouldn't capture the first or last element of projectIds, so the best way  without changing schema would be to read the entire table and parse it programatically.

Comment: yeah was thinking of doing the post filter after the query and see how performance is. Otherwise i guess ill change the schema

Comment: `LIKE '%,1,%'` would not locate `1,2,3` as there is no **`,`** before **1,......**

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a User Defined Function (UDF), that knows how to work with your comma-separated values.  With PDO, you can use [`PDO::sqliteCreateFunction()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php) to make a PHP function available in SQL statements.

The following defines a UDF that calculates the intersection of two comma-separated strings of values and uses it to filter rows in a query.

```
function csv_intersection($vals, $search) {
    $vals_array   = explode(',', $vals);
    $search_array = explode(',', $search);
    $intersection = array_intersect($vals_array, $search_array);
    return implode(',', $intersection);
}

// $db is a PDO instance
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('intersection', 'csv_intersection', 2);

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name, vals FROM example WHERE intersection(vals, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array('1,2,3'));
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

» [See this example running online](https://3v4l.org/AbcAR)

Answer (score 1):

A search pattern `LIKE '%,1,%'` will fail to match a value like `'1,3,4'`.  
 
So you have to compare it to values like `',1,3,4,'`.  
To do that you have to append `,` at the beginning and at the end of the value of the column `projectIds` after removing (if any) all white spaces with `REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 
  ',' || REPLACE(projectIds, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,1,%'
  OR
  ',' || REPLACE(projectIds, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,2,%'
  OR
  ',' || REPLACE(projectIds, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,3,%'
  OR
  ',' || REPLACE(projectIds, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,4,%'
```

This is the code that suits your current table structure. 
.
Of course you must change this structure to something more flexible.